# Spring datasource hibernate enconding

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I tried every solution I found on the internet but some diacritics aren't saved to mysql 5.7.17 database. ( some of romanian diacritics are saved and some not: țșă - aren't saved, but â and î are saved ).

Connection url:

```
jdbc:mysql://dbserver:3306/dbtest?useUnicode=true&amp;connectionCollation=utf8mb4_general_ci&amp;characterSetResults=utf8mb4&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Databasa Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci  and tried utf8_general_ci
Storage Engine: InnoDB

Java model contains String properties and the are set like:

```
model.setAuthor(new String(author.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
```

Database is hosted on Linux, "locale" command output:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Mysql conf:

```
mysql> show variables like "%character%";show variables like "%collation%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+----------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Other spring properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.sqlScriptEncoding=UTF-8
```

Someone had similar problem and can suggest some solutions ?

Thanks.